# Product vs. join of subgroups of a finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, galois-theory, minimal-polynomials, galois-extensions

Hypotheses:

- $G$ is a finite group
- $A$ and $B$ are subgroups if $G$.

Definitions:

- $AB = \{ ab \mathbin{|} a \in A, b \in B \}$ is the product of $A$ and $B$
- $A \vee B$ is the join of (subgroup of $G$ generated by) $A$ and $B$
- $A \wedge B$ is the intersection $A$ and $B$ (a subgroup of $G$)

It is known that $|AB|$ is equal to $|A||B| \mathbin{/} |A \wedge B|$,
and that $|AB|$ is less than or equal to $|A \vee B|$.

Question: Is $|AB|$ a divisor of $|A \vee B|$ ?
If so, I would like to have a proof.
If not, I would like to have a concrete counter-example.

**UPDATE (Galois theoretic motivation)**

Let $L$ be a normal extension of the rationals, and let $G$ be its
Galois group. Let $\alpha$ be some element of $L$, generating a
subfield fixed by the subgroup $A$ of $G$. The degree of the minimal
polynomial $f(x)$ of $\alpha$ over $Q$ is then $[G : A]$. Consider now
the subfield $K$ of $L$ fixed by some subgroup $B$ of $G$. The minimal
polynomial $g(x)$ of $\alpha$ over $K$ is a divisor of $f(x)$ and has
degree $[B : A \wedge B]$. <strike>In particular, the degree of $g(x)$ is a
divisor of the degree of $f(x)$, that is, $[B : A \wedge B]$ is a
divisor of $[G : A]$.</strike>

Now, for any finite group $G$ and subgroups $A$ and $B$ holds:
$$
    1
    = \frac{|AB||A \wedge B|}{(|A||B|)}
 \leq \frac{|A \vee B||A \wedge B|}{(|A||B|)}
 \leq \frac{|G||A \wedge B|}{(|A||B|)}
  =   \frac{[G : A]}{[B : A \wedge B]}
$$

The full question would thus be whether all these values are integers
or not, considering the case that $G$ is the Galois group of some
normal extension of the rationals as well as the case that $G$ is an
arbitrary finite group.

What is known:

- <strike>If $G$ is the Galois group of a normal extension of the rationals,
  then $[G : A] \mathbin{/} [B : A \wedge B]$ is an integer.</strike>
- $|AB|$ is not necessarily a divisor of $|A \vee B|$ (answer to this
  question)

**UPDATE (wrong claim)**

I did a mistake: $g(x)$ is a divisor of $f(x)$, but the degree of $g(x)$ is not necessarily a divisor of the degree of $f(x)$. This
invalidates the question, I was on a wrong path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $G=S_3$, $A=\langle (1\ 2)\rangle$, $B=\langle (1\ 3)\rangle$. Then $A\vee B=\langle (1\ 2),(1\ 3)\rangle=S_3$, and $AB=\{(1),(1\ 2),(1\ 3),(1\ 3\ 2)\}$. So $|AB|=4$, $|A\vee B|=6$. Therefore $|AB|$ is not a divisor of $|A\vee B|$.